# Creating Autofill Facebook VB Form

Tags: vba, web

I am trying to construct a Visual Basic form where there is a web-browser that opens up to a website, depending on an icon I click on an icon stationed in a menu strip. The code I have for the autofill is as follows:

```
WebBrowser1.document.getelementbyid("user").innerhtml = "TestUser"
WebBrowser1.document.getelementbyid("pass").innerhtml = "TestPass"
```

For some reason this does not work, even though I got something similar to work in my own custom html page in class. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a similar program not too long ago. Although your first instinct may be to user the .innerhtml you should really make your code like this:

```
WebBrowser1.document.getelementbyid("user").setattribute("value", "TestUser")
WebBrowser1.document.getelementbyid("pass").setattribute =("value", "TestPass")
```

Assuming you have the ID's for the fields you want to edit correct, this should work.
You should also be sure you double click on your web browser to make sure you are putting this code into the _pagecompleted section of code as it will not work otherwise.